# How to get an undirected double quote symbol

Tags: symbols

My problem is that I want want to have an undirected quote character in my thesis (the " character), when I mention it's function in a certain file format. The left and right double quote symbols used to show quotes in latex simply looks off for this purpose (among other reasons because I already use it for quotes in other parts of the text), and the solution with using prime marks in math mode ([suggested here](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2006-July/006545.html)) looks horrible.

Is there any way to insert a plain double quotes sign (") that doesn't lean left or right short of inserting an image in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please tell in what context the straight double quote character is to be used?

Comment: If you mean context as where in the tex-file, I wish to use it in the middle of a stretch of plain text, not in math mode or any other special environment. For now it stands like this: Then each item will be wrapped in double quotes (''), and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

" Just use plain double quotes  "

\end{document}
```

[image]